# ReactDOM.render not accepting JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, webpack, jsx

I cannot get ReactDOM.render(...) to accept any JSX tag, however if I use React.createElement(...) it works.

This is my **index.jsx** file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// THIS WORKS!
//var elem = React.createElement('h1',{},"Hello");
//ReactDOM.render(elem, document.getElementById("content"));

// THIS DOESN'T WORK!
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World!</h1>, document.getElementById("content"));
```

In the **index.html** file there is a div with id="content" somewhere.

This is my **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "static",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack -p --progress --config webpack.config.js",
    "dev-build": "webpack --progress -d --config webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "webpack --progress -d --config webpack.config.js --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.35.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5"
  },
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

This is my **webpack.config.js** file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

const config = {
    entry:  __dirname + '/js/index.jsx',

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
};
module.exports = config;

module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: 'babel-loader'
    }
  ]
}
```

The **error** I am getting is:

```
ERROR in ./js/index.jsx 11:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| 
> ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World!</h1>, document.getElementById("content"));
|
```

## ==============================================

**Solution:**

1st of all the **webpack.config.js** was wrong (see accepted answer).
After, I had to install **babel-loader** with `npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack` and then created **.babelrc** file at the same path of the other config. files, with the content:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Comment: Is that your full package.json file? Where's react, babel, babel-loader etc...?

Comment: as mentioned: you seem to be missing quite a few essential dependencies.

Comment: It is possible that I am missing stuff, yes. I'm just starting with this thing and I am following this: https://codeburst.io/creating-a-full-stack-web-application-with-python-npm-webpack-and-react-8925800503d9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing the rules in the wrong place.

the correct config is:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

const config = {
    entry:  __dirname + '/js/index.jsx',

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: 'babel-loader'
        }
      ]
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Updated the file, however now I am getting: ```ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in (...)\static```

Comment: You must install babel-loader as a dev dependency and you must be sure to setup .babelrc with the right plugins